# Request view and model in router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to pass the hum data model view to Para , and after paragraph hum undescore model , that being the eStara model Within A page requested. Follows the code :

```js
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        return '/api/rest/album/id/' + this.id
    }
});

var AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.content-page',
    template: 'album',
    render: function () {
        this.model.fetch({
            success: function (data) {}
        });
    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'album/:id': 'albumPage'
    },
    albumPage: function (id) {
        var dados_alb = new Model({
            id: id
        });
        dados_alb.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.get('alb_nome'));
            }
        });
    }
});
```